# HTML5 video duration

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

Here i have a javascript function:

```
function displayDuration(){
var vdo = document.getElementById('v');
document.getElementById('dur').innerHTML = vdo.currentTime+" / "+vdo.duration;
}
```

which i can call like this: `<button onclick='displayDuration()'>Display duration</button>`

but i would like to display the current time in a div, without the button right from the beginning such that it continues to update it self dynamically, just like youtube.

Please help!

Comment: Pretty sure these properties are unique to the API / video host provider.

Comment: @jdero — The question is tagged `html5`; the API is standardised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys but i found my answer:

```
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById('screen');
vid.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(){
//whatever
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bind the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to the [video's `timeupdate` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents) instead of a button's `click` event, or run it via [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

Comment: I don't think intrinsic event attributes (which are horrible anyway) have been created for the newer event types. Use `addEventListener`.